# how to insert part of image into picturebox?

Tags: c#, image, location, picturebox, partial

I'm not really sure if it is possible to insert a part of image into picturebox, but I would like to create an image 500*500 pixels in size and then use the parts of it as small connectable 50*50 pieces by setting the location of image inside the pictureboxes...

Is anything similar possible through use of graphics? I'm not very familiar with it... (I am talking about C# forms application...)

Comment: Yes, it is possible, but I doubt anyone will give you full solution. Do some research first, try something and come back with a specific problem, when it won't work as expected. (of course with the source code, so we can find the problem)

Comment: I didn't actually went for: "gimme code plz??". I should've expressed myself a bit better, I am looking for guidelines to where to look? :)

Comment: You might find this sample project useful: [Crop the image from Windows Forms PictureBox control (CSWinFormCropImage)](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/CSWinFormCropImage-d4beb1fa). It would be trivial to remove the part that allows mouse selection and use just the cropping part of the code.

Comment: The last part looks usefull, thanks Cody.

Comment: It's late so I'll hit the bed, will post the solution here if I come up with it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some time of searching and few personal attempts I have found a solution, this isn't my own, but sadly I have forgot where did I took it from:

```
   private static Image cropImage(Image img, Rectangle cropArea)
   {
       Bitmap bmpImage = new Bitmap(img);
       Bitmap bmpCrop = bmpImage.Clone(cropArea,
       bmpImage.PixelFormat);
       return (Image)(bmpCrop);
   }
```

This will created cropped image, you can now use it in code. SAMPLE:

```
   Picturebox P = new Picturebox;
   P.BackgroundImage = cropImage(ImageThatWillBeCropped, new Rectangle(0,0,50,50));
```

If anyone finds this useful and needs explanation for rectangle, please, feel free to ask :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your good answer.
It is better to p.Image:

```
P.Image = cropImage(ImageThatBeCropped, new Rectangle(0, 0, 50,50));
```

To see image in real size.