# display very large 1bpp bitmap in C#

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am loading binary files as 1bpp bitmap into imagebox (my picturebox with ability to zoom and pan images witch inherited ScrollableControl). and i have no problem with little ones. I read a byte array from the file and convert it to bitmap like this:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);
BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, bmp.PixelFormat);
Marshal.Copy(data, 0, bmpData.Scan0, data.Length);
bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
this.Image = bmp;
```

but when it comes to large files my problem begins. I want to deal with files in size of more than 20gb. obviously i can't load all of the file at once in to the memory, and i have to load part of the file that it need to be display on the imagebox. I want to know is there a tool/way to ease my problem?

Comment: Something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15512392/how-to-insert-part-of-image-into-picturebox) SO question?

Comment: Even displaying every pixel on a 4K screen, it is just less than 100MB. Select the pixels you are displaying from your 20GB file.

Comment: @Tommy this is exactly what i wanted you to help me with. as scroll event happens I need to load part of the file and show it in Imagebox.

Comment: @JeroenHeier problem in that question is to crop an image that is loaded into memory. but my problem is witch part of the file needs to be loaded into memory and when it supposed to happen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using a Deep Zoom technology. There is a description here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645077(v=vs.95).aspx

The gist of Deep Zoom is that very large image files can be broken up into many 'tiles' that are significantly smaller than the original image. A client utilizing Deep Zoom would only load the tiles that are required to display whatever portion of the original image is in the view port similar to how Google Maps works.